# How to set indivisual column colour in Amcharts stock column chart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Hi I want to set alternate column colour for each column .
[fiddle](http://%20%20jsfiddle.net/rbz7312m/)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/rbz7312m/

Comment: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/automatically-apply-theme-colors-to-each-individual-column/

Comment: @Mahi - you have the right idea but it glosses over the details a bit as it is implementing a plugin to apply theme colors to each column, making it a bit overkill for what he's trying to do. You also need to perform an extra step when using stock charts as explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

@Mahi has the right idea, but the link points to a plugin-based solution that applies colors from the current chart theme so it glosses over the details.

To elaborate further, when setting individual column (or line/bullet) colors, you have to define a `lineColorField` and `fillColorsField` in your graph object and then set the color in your data. For example, in your data:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2016-11-25",
    "value": 3,
    "color": "#ff0000"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-11-26",
    "value": 3,
    "color": "#00ff00"
  },
  // ...
]
```

And then in your graph object:

```
"graphs": [{
  "lineColorField": "color",
  "fillColorsField": "color", // if your chart has a fill like a column or area line graph
  // ...
}]
```

Or stock chart's stockGraph:

```
"stockGraphs": [{
  "lineColorField": "color",
  "fillColorsField": "color", // if your chart has a fill like a column or area line graph
  // ...
}]
```

For stock charts like your fiddle, you also need to set the categoryAxesSettings' `maxSeries` property to 0 as it cannot apply your custom colors while its data grouping functionality is enabled.

```
"categoryAxesSettings": {
  "maxSeries": 0,
  // ...
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rbz7312m/3/